# Telebot дубликаты сообщений, если несколько раз нажать на кнопку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Telebot дубликаты сообщений, если несколько раз нажать на кнопку

К примеру нажал кнопку "Назад" дабл кликом, после этого что не вызываешь дублируется, почему?

```python
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.row('Привет')

    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, main_message)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def main_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ура')


print('Bot started')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы думаете мы экстрасенсы? Код выложите

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: та же причина в телеграмм...стали дублироваться сообщения..нажимаю один раз..но туда приходят два сообщения..до этого было всё нормально...это кнопка какая то нажата..не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Ну так вы же нажимаете на кнопку два раза само собой он будет два раза возвращать ответ... Кнопку вы не удаляете, а надо бы раз у вас такая проблема.

```
keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
```

Comment: Так я нажимаю кнопку 2 раза один раз, а последующие разы нажимаю кнопку уже 1 раз а получаю два дубля в ответ

Comment: В вашем коде этого нет